# How do I print a single comment in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-comments

I want to print a individual comment in drupal based on it's comment ID. How can I do this? Google and other sources have yielded me nothing. Thank you.

Comment: What is the context of this?  Do you want to have a page that's just a comment?  A block?  Make it part of a page template?  Print a single comment in a node template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eaton's suggestion is good (except it's `{comments}`, not `{comment}`) if you need to display the comment like core does it, including the info coming from the node. Except the default theme_comment implementation in `modules/comment/comment.tpl.php` makes no use of $node.

However, I'd do it slightly differently, because if you need to extract a single comment, displaying it with the normal content formatting provided by `comment.tpl.php` is likely to be inappropriate.

```
function print_comment($cid) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM {comment} c WHERE c.cid = %d";
  if ($comment = db_fetch_object(db_rewrite_sql(db_query($sql, $cid), 'c'))) {
    return theme('my_special_comment_formatting', $comment);
  }
}
```

And of course, define this special commment formatting in your module's `hook_theme()` implementation, inspired by what `comment.tpl.php` does.

2014-02 UPDATE: note that this is a 2009 question/answer. In Drupal 8, you just don't want to access the hypothetical underlying SQL database (and would not do it like this anyway, but use DBTNG), but just use something like:

```
if ($comment = entity_load('comment', $cid)) {
  return entity_view($comment, $view_mode);
}
```

Comment: Hah. Thanks for noting the comment/comments distinction. I'd popped open api.drupal.org and not noticed I was looking at the D7 version of the code -- the table name has changed to singular in the new dev release.

Comment: Also, you'll get some PHP notices if there isn't a node object passed in -- $node->type is used to construct possible template options (like comment-story.tpl.php) in the default phptemplate\_preprocess\_comment function.

Comment: `phptemplate_preprocess_comment` won't be used when invoking theme('my_special_comment_formatting'), though. But good catch for `theme('comment')` !

I had only checked the template, not the preprocess function.

Answer (score 3):

```
function print_comment($cid) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM {comments} WHERE cid = %d";
  if ($comment = db_fetch_object(db_query($sql, $cid))) {
    $node = node_load($comment->nid);
    return theme('comment', $comment, $node);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No reason to use any sql to do this, two drupal api function calls is all it takes.

```
function print_comment($cid) 
{
    $comment = _comment_load($cid);
    return theme('comment',$comment);
}
```